# Building android application using platform tools

Tags: android

Does anybody know sources in internet where described how to build an android application using it's native components such as aapt, aidl, dex, apkbuilder, etc.? Because in [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html) link there is only description of how to build an application using ant tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant uses the native tools. There are very few guides available on how to actually run the aapt/aidl/dex/etc tools at a command prompt, and in general Ant performs all the tasks you'd like here. Is there a specific reason you don't want to use Ant?

Comment: I would like to understand how does the loop of this tools work indeed during building an application. You said that there is some guides which describe this process. Could you give me a source?

Comment: I'll assume you've already gone through http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html. The best way to go about it is looking at the source code for the ant tasks: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/sdk.git;a=tree;f=anttasks;h=88577c0fd7927d6369e414a7e148feb2d448fa6a;hb=HEAD

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link I will look through)))